# Retrieving data extension data from a WSProxy retrieve

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, ssjs, wsproxy

I'm drawing a total blank.  I have the following code to retrieve data from a data extension:

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">
   Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");
   var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
   var deCustomerKey = "DE NAME HERE";
  
   var data = api.retrieve(
     "DataExtensionObject[" + deCustomerKey + "]", 
     ["AutoName", "ErrorRecipient", "MID"]
    );
  
   Write(Stringify(data));
</script>
```

The output I receive on the browser is obviously the API response.  This is going to be a completely dumb question and I've tried Googling it, but how do I take this response data and "parse" it out?  I've tried `Platform.Function.ParseJSON(data)` and that doesn't work (500 Error).

Answer (score 4):

You need to use dot notation and index numbers to interact with arrays and objects to get specific information from it.

For instance:

```js
data.Results[i] 
//where i is an iterative for the index of each object/array inside of the Results array
//for example
data.Results[0]
```

and for an object:

```js
data.Results[0].Properties[0].Name  
//This then pulls the first result and first of objects in the properites array to grab the name of the property
```

Using these in combination will get you what you need from the array and object.